# Why do I get the error message "element … not processed" when parsing a KML with Geo::KML?

Tags: xml, perl, kml

```
use Geo::KML;
my $data = Geo::KML->readKML("test1.kml");

use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
print Dumper $data;
```

I am using this code and the `test1.kml` file is available from http://pastebin.com/LbzwLYLc. I am getting this error:

```
error: element `{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Document' not processed at {http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}kml
```

Comment: It would be great for other users if the original poster could explain if @Dabhaid answer below is correct, or if the original poster just forgot to complete the full XML in the paste.

Answer (score 0):

If the pastebin is the full contents of what you are parsing, it might be because you are missing closing `</Folder>` and `</kml>` tags. This might be consistent with the error message (though I'd expect it to refer to Folder) - then the Document/Folder element under  is not processed (because it isn't closed).